# Why did Hogwarts expel Hagrid?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, hagrid

Hagrid is expelled from Hogwarts as a student, but he said that the courtesy of Dumbledore let him stay as a gamekeeper. Why did Hogwarts expel him?

Comment: Have you read the books or seen the movies? It is explained in both.

Comment: @TylerH – it isn't helpful to answer a question by saying "go read thousands of pages and watch hours of movies"

Comment: @JeffThompson Actually it is, since it forms a major subplot of *Chamber of Secrets*. Any answer is therefore by definition a spoiler. It's not even something which anyone reading it could possibly misunderstand. So in every way this is a bad question. The only correct answer is "read the books" (or "watch the films"), and the only correct verdict on the question is -1.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Simple laziness in wanting an answer without reading the books. We are not here as a precis service.

Comment: @Graham this question is perfectly fine and that is not a reason to vote to close. _Maybe_ downvote but certainly not close. Also you might want to sort out your attitude and be a bit nicer to folks.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot "Please explain the plot of a book I can't be bothered to read and can't be bothered to Google" isn't a good use of people's time on any forum. IMO of course.

Comment: @Graham then downvote and move on. Others clearly feel differently and that doesn’t change the fact that, that isn’t a reason to vote to close.

Comment: @Graham – dunno what the point of this forum is then: the answer to any question could be "read the books" or "watch the movies." Clearly someone thought this worth posting. I agree with TheLethalCarrot – this kind of quick-to-close attitude is what has plagued Stack Exchange for years (and something Stack Overflow has actively been working to curb)

Comment: @Graham – also, the discussion in the accepted answer shows this is more subtle than you're suggesting

Comment: @JeffThompson If the question was about something which could be confusing, of course that's fair. And if it was about the strangely incompetent investigation, of course that's also fair. But how blatant does it have to be to be worth closing? Would "I've only read half the first book - how does Harry beat Voldemort in the end?" also be OK? And if you can easily find that information on the relevant Wikipedia page, that IMO should be an automatic close. I'm happy to be a minority opinion, but it doesn't change or invalidate my opinion.

Comment: @JeffThompson Stack Exchange sites expect a modicum of effort in their questions, the least of which is to be somewhat familiar with the subject you're asking about. In this case, it's not "*go read thousands of pages and watch hours of movies*", it's "read a chapter of one book" or even "watch one movie". Hardly too much to ask; OP can easily answer this Q themselves by experiencing the source material, even *casually*. I see you don't really ever downvote, unfortunately; if you hover over the downvote arrow, you'll see it says "this question doesn't show any research effort".

Comment: @JeffThompson see [How do I ask a good question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is voting important?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for more information on those important topics.

Comment: @Graham lack of research is a downvote reason, not a close vote reason. That's a pretty solid network-wide stance (I say this as perhaps one of the most prolific close voters across said network at over 44k cast).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In *The Chamber of Secrets*, it is revealed that Hagrid was expelled because it is suspected that he is responsible for the death of a Muggle born witch.

> Now known as the ghost "Moaning Myrtle".

This death was the result of the creature that resides in the Chamber of Secrets, which had been opened by the "Heir of Slytherin":

> Tom Riddle, aka Lord Voldemort.

However, Hagrid was framed, because the headmaster at the time, Armando Dippet, was convinced that the death was instead caused by Hagrid's "pet":

> Aragog, the Acromantula.

The reason that he was expelled and allowed to remain on as gamekeeper is that the existence of the Chamber of Secrets was not generally known. Cuthbert Binns says as much in *The Chamber of Secrets*:

> But these honest facts have been obscured by the fanciful legend of the Chamber of Secrets. The story goes that Slytherin had built a hidden chamber in the castle [...]

And Hagrid is not believed to have intentionally killed the victim, just that he brought dangerous creatures into the castle:

> I don't think you meant to kill anyone. But monsters don't make good pets. I suppose you just let it out for exercise and -

This indirect association with the death, combined with Dumbledore's intervention, meant that he was only expelled, and not given a more serious punishment. The school administration treated it as an accident.

> Only the Transfiguration teacher, Dumbledore, seemed to think Hagrid was innocent. He persuaded Dippet to keep Hagrid and train him as gamekeeper. Yes, I think Dumbledore might have guessed. Dumbledore never seemed to like me as much as the other teachers did…

Comment: I always thought that there was a subtext to the story where substantial bias against Hagrid existed because he was part giant.  And that he was expelled as soon as any whiff of an accusation could be brought against him, to make sure that a part-giant wouldn't become a wizard - even though the accusation was not very plausible, and everyone knew that there wasn't any evidence that would support sending him to Azkahban.

Comment: @tbrookside I think racism certainly played a role, but honestly he got off pretty lightly considering the circumstances. From their point of view, he knowingly brought a dangerous creature into the castle, and it escaped and caused a death. That's reckless  endangerment (he knew or should have known the creature was a deadly threat, and did it anyway) leading to involuntary manslaughter, which is either a high degree misdemeanor or a low end felony. Getting off with just expulsion is a pretty good outcome on a charge that could easily have carried up to ten years in prison.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: Ah, but what is the penalty for a minor (noting that as a student at Hogwarts, Hagrid would have definitely have been a minor)? It is possible that, due to his age, no criminal charges were brought, but expulsion for breaking school rules (seeing as a giant spider is not "a cat, owl OR toad") is still on the table.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I see your point, I'm just saying that I thought there was a sense, or implication, that everyone knew that there really was no proof that Hagrid was guilty but he made a convenient scapegoat for an event they were otherwise unable or unwilling to explain.  And that they were much happier to turn their half-giant student into a menial worker than have him become a full-fledged wizard.  (Other than his defenders on the staff, including Dumbledore.)

Comment: In real life law, a minor can still be found guilty and sent to juvenile detention, which is still prison. And at 15 years old, Hagrid could have easily been charged as an adult (14 is the usual minimum for that). He wasn't being punished for breaking the pet rules, he was being punished for recklessly negligent homicide. Getting off with mere expulsion is a win under the circumstances.  (And yes, Tom Riddle was manipulating the whole thing, not the point.)

Comment: @tbrookside I disagree; Tom found out Hagrid was raising an acromantula and intentionally framed him for the death. While racism may have played a part in not looking deeper than the obvious, if somebody gets shot and you're in possession of the only (known) gun in town, "you don't KNOW that I pulled the trigger" isn't much of a defense. The lack of conclusive direct evidence is likely one of the factors Dumbledore used to argue for mere expulsion.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym That's fair.  To me it seemed unlikely that the staff of Hogwarts, with all the abilities at their disposal, sincerely mistook injuries from a basilisk attack for injuries from an acromantula attack.  But I'm making that determination by implication and inference, so it's certainly possible I'm wrong and you're right.

Comment: Well, you're correct -- I suspect there's some garbled editing in there, because "poisonous giant snake bite mistaken for poisonous giant spider bite" is a coherent plot point, while "petrified to death" probably can't be mistaken for "giant spider attack".

Comment: @DarthPseudonym : the problem in the case of Hagrid is also that there were no Acromantula (or any) bite marks on the victim. It must have been a really sloppy investigation, especially as with magic you could probably have much better ways of identifying the cause of death.

Comment: "Look, we just want  this wrapped up. Kid's a Muggleborn. Her parents will never be back here. If it was up to me, I'd have given 'em the standard 'Never had a kid, always wanted to move to Australia' Memory Charm."

Comment: "It must have been a really sloppy investigation, especially as..." -- especially as you could just _ask the victim_, as Harry does many years later.

Comment: Re, "...only expelled, and not given a more serious punishment." Expelled _and_ forbidden to use his own magic for the rest of his life! That sounds kind of serious.

Comment: @tbrookside Hagrid's ancestry also wasn't necessarily well known at the time. If I remember correctly, it's a major plot point in a later book when Rita Skeeter publishes the scoop that he had a giant for a mother, which could only be the case if it wasn't common knowledge already. Draco Malfoy says he thought Hagrid was large because he drank a bottle of Skele-Grow, so the size-parentage connection isn't so strong that a giant parent is the obvious explanation.

Comment: @Upper_Case: Perhaps not common knowledge, but in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* we learn how Hogwarts handled a student who was a werewolf: the staff was aware, but other students (and their parents) did not. So Rita Skeeter's scoop doesn't tell us anything about whether Dippet and other decision-makers in Hagrid's case knew that he was half-giant.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Dumbledores intervention might have played role in Hagrid not being incriminated at Azkaban.